# specifying a string to date datatype using pyspark

Tags: filter, pyspark, partition

I want to filter a parquet partitioned by date.
When I apply the filter

```
.filter(col('DATE')>= '2020-08-01')
```

It casts the value `2020-08-01` as a string when doing the filtering as shown in the physical plan. I read that this is not efficient and results in a whole filescan.

> PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(DATE#5535), (cast(DATE#5535 as string) >= 2020-08-01)]

How do I cast the `string` as `date` in the filter clause? All the examples on the internet mention to use `to_date` but that works only on columns.
Is this possible, or even worth it?
Please advise.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
.filter(F.expr(" `Date` >= to_date('2020-08-01','yyyy-MM-dd' )"))
```

Comment: I tried that but am getting the following error: `\nextraneous input '<EOF>' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 45)\n\n== SQL ==\n `DATE` >= to_date('2020-08-01','yyyy-MM-dd' \n---------------------------------------------^^^\n"`

Comment: @thentangler missing `)` at the end of clause. Fixed IMO.

Comment: Thank You, The double quotes are actually after the first closing bracket. The following worked for me:
```f.expr(" `DATE` >= to_date('2020-08-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) ") )```